# ReactJS - Call function AFTER ComponentDidMount Only Once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I noticed in ReactJS documentation that ComponentDidUpdate is used to call anything as the DOM updates after the run of ComponentDidMount is called on initial render.

However, I'm trying to think of the optimal way to call a function AFTER ComponentDidMount is run. This COULD be done after ComponentDidMount is run via a call in ComponentDidUpdate with a javascript counter variable, but I'm thinking there has to be a much better way.

The problem is when I call a function that changes the DOM in a specific way:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.setInterval(() => this.loadTicketsFromServer(), this.props.pollInterval);
    if (this.userState.data.privilegeLevel == 1) {
        this.setAppSwitch();
    }

    this.showMyTickets();
}
```

It throws an error, which I think is due to the fact that a function is trying to change the DOM when not everything is quite loaded yet, if I understand that correctly. For those who wonder, here's the code in the showMyTickets function:

```
showMyTickets() {
    var currUser = this.userState.data;
    //alert(currUser.userName);
    //alert(currUser.userId);
    //alert(this.state.data.map(owner => owner.userOwnerId));
    var myTix = this.state.data.filter(x => x.userOwnerId == currUser.userId);
    var myCloses = this.state.closedData.filter(x => x.userOwnerId == currUser.userId);
    //console.log("Just filtered to " + JSON.stringify(myTix));
    //alert(myTix);
    if (!myTix || myTix.length == 0) {
        //alert(myTix);
        $('#affirmTable').hide();
        $('#noTixNotice').show();
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ selectedData: myTix });
        $('#affirmTable').show();
        $('.ticketSearchBar').show();
        $('#noTixNotice').hide();
    }
    if (myCloses.length > 0) {
        //alert(myTix);
        this.setState({ selClosedData: myCloses });
    }
    $("#myTix").addClass('active');
    $("#allTix").removeClass('active');
    this.setState({ selectedMine: true });
}
```

And yes, the function is bound with the bind() function when the React page is first loaded.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

EDIT: Per previous suggestions, I've tried using the following logic in the render section of the React DOM, but it doesn't seem to update the active button as expected:

```
{!this.selectedMine ? 
                <div>
                <button class="btn btn-info active" id="allTix" onClick={this.showAllTickets}>All Tasks</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="myTix" onClick={this.showMyTickets}>My Tasks</button>
                {this.userState.data.privilegeLevel == 1 && <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onClick={this.showCreateModal} >New Task</button>}
                </div> :
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" id="allTix" onClick={this.showAllTickets}>All Tasks</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info active" id="myTix" onClick={this.showMyTickets}>My Tasks</button>
                    {this.userState.data.privilegeLevel == 1 && <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onClick={this.showCreateModal} >New Task</button>}
                </div>}
```

Comment: take out all that jquery, use state values and dynamically set the classes/styles and your errors will go away. it's bad practice to use jquery like this with react

Comment: I think the root cause of your issue is that you're making manipulations on the DOM with jQuery. It's ill-advised to mix a virtual-DOM library (like React) and jQuery. Can you refactor `showMyTickets` to be handled entirely by React?

Comment: @MattAft what would you just as an alternative to adding/removing the active class of buttons in order to show that the corresponding items are being rendered?

Comment: Are the suggestions to basically use React to REMOVE my components instead of hiding them?

Comment: @KieranOjakangas you should be able to find a lot of resources in the docs. here's for conditionally rendering your components: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Guys, this conditional rendering doesn't seem to work? {!this.selectedMine ? 
                    <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info active" id="allTix" onClick={this.showAllTickets}>All Tasks</button>
                    ...}
                    </div> :
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-info" id="allTix" onClick={this.showAllTickets}>All Tasks</button>
                        ...}

Comment: @KieranOjakangas it's based off state values, so should probably be `this.state.selectedMine`